# Is there R code to test if variable is a function

Tags: r, function, testing

I am trying to write a function `myfun` in which one of the variables `fun`, say, is  itself a function. A simple, but ludicrous, example is:

```
myfun <- function(fun){
              return(fun(1))
             }
```

In line with good practice, I want to insert into `myfun`  a test of `fun` to ensure that `fun` is indeed a function.

But I can't find code for any such test. What should I do?

Comment: Can you show few inputs and corresponding output of how this function will behave?

Comment: `is.function`  may be

Comment: @PKumar if you give that comment as an Answer I shall accept it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is.function` to check if some object is a function, for example:

`is.function(mean)` or `` is.function(`[[`) `` would return **TRUE**, also on a side note there is another function is.primitive which tests for builtins and specials, but in your case you probably would want `is.function`

In your case :

```
myfun <- function(fun){
              if(is.function(fun)){
                 return(fun(1))
              } else {
                 warning("You are not passing fun as function")
              }
          }
```

Testing using:

```
fun <- function(x)x+2
```

would yield `3`, but `fun <- 1` it would give you warning for calls on `myfun(fun)`